# loop devices are always in sync with their file?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm doing this operations:

1. download an img file of a complete Linux system (i.e. Raspbian)
2. `losetup -P /dev/loop0 image.img`
3. `mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/rootfs`
4. do anything under `/mnt/rootfs/*` subfolders

When I want to burn an SD card with the updated system I have to:

- unmount the `/dev/loop0p2` ?
- detach the loop device with `losetup -D` ?

or the changes are always in sync with `image.img` so I can use this file in the meanwhile its partitions are in the loop device and mounted in the host filesystem?

Comment: The same rules that apply to USB thumb drives of course also apply here.

Comment: Well, I know the USB pen drive should be unmounted before it remove from the port. But I don't know the underlying caveats about the loop device. Would you mind to be more explicit please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is run `sync` to make sure that all data from RAM is on the filesystem.